# Ruby Error: "(SystemStackError) stack level too deep" while Puppet installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems, puppet

I have searched for a solution to this ruby error "(SystemStackError) stack level too deep". I understand it is a general/common error message from it. But any idea why this error is showing up when we try to install a puppet client in a live server?. Following is full error I got.

```
# gem install puppet --version 2.7.11
Successfully installed puppet-2.7.11

RDoc::Parser::Ruby failure around line 224 of
lib/puppet/parser/scope.rb

Before reporting this, could you check that the file you're documenting
has proper syntax:

  /usr/bin/ruby -c lib/puppet/parser/scope.rb

RDoc is not a full Ruby parser and will fail when fed invalid ruby programs.

The internal error was:

    (SystemStackError) stack level too deep

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (SystemStackError)
    stack level too deep
```

I'm trying to install Puppet client version 2.7.11 since to match with Puppet master version in another server. Honestly I have zero knowledge in Ruby, so I expect some help from here :). Ruby and Gem version is server as follows:

```
# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]
~
# gem -v
2.4.7
```

Comment: Wow, that gem has likely not been touched in a *long* time. Have you tried `gem install --no-rdoc`? That might work around the issue.

Comment: Thank you, but still same error